# How to check primary key condition in a SQL query?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

The problem statement is :

Let W(A,B) be a relation schema. The domain of A is `INTEGER` and the domain of B is `VARCHAR(5)`.

Write a SQL query with returns the A-values of tuples in W if A is a
primary key of W. Otherwise, i.e., if A is not a primary key, then the
query should return the A-values of tuples in W for which the primary
key property is violated.

How can I check primary key condition in a SQL query?

Comment: How would the primary key be violated, if you set it up with a UNIQUE constraint?

Comment: I removed all the DBMS tags. Feel free to add back the one you actually are using. You also should clarify your question. As it is posted it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: plz send teh codez :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer to this problem which is as follows:

```
SELECT W."A" FROM "W" W WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT W1."A" FROM "W" W1,"W" W2 WHERE
W1."A" = W2."A" AND W1."B" <> W2."B")
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT W."A" FROM "W" W WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM "W" W1,"W" W2 WHERE W."A" = W1."A" AND
W1."A" = W2."A" AND W1."B" <> W2."B")
```

Answer (score 0):

In **SQL-SERVER**:

If you want to a Query to check the constraints (especially the Primary Key) of a table you can use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS` as a table like that:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE TABLE_NAME='YourTable' 
--If you only want the column that has the CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
--AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
```

Let me know if that answers your question.